# How can I, in Javascript, set a time limit to get a response from a server before throwing an error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have some Javascript code that grabs data from a server in a jQuery ajax call, and it seems to always trigger the success callback, even when it didn't get the proper data. The error callback never gets triggered as its supposed to. I want to set a time limit on the success so if the data isn't grabbed quick enough, an error is thrown. How might I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried function?
setTimeout();

Usage :

```
setTimeout(function(){
    // a function you want to do
}, timeLimit);
//timeLimit : time as miliseconds. 2000 means 2 seconds.
// example : 
setTimeout(function(){
    alert("Hello World");
},2000);
```

Comment: I'm confused tho; I know how to use "setTimeout" to make something happen after x-many seconds, but I need a function that waits for another function to occur within a time period, and if that function does not occur/finish, THEN the waiting function acts.

Comment: javascript is asynchronous. But I can recommend you to llok this : https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

Answer (score 1):

Set the [`timeout` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/timeout) on the object.

```js
const url = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://example.com/";

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.timeout = 5; // This is very small to demo it!
xhr.addEventListener("load", () => console.log("Loaded!"));
xhr.addEventListener("timeout", () => console.log("Timed out!"));
xhr.addEventListener("error", () => console.log("Error!"));
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 1):

In ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
success: function(data){
    //Success code
},
url: "your_url",
error: function(data){
    //Error code
},
timeout: 6000 // sets timeout to 6 seconds
});
```